# Google Cloud Composer DAG relative directory in GCS bucket

Tags: output, google-cloud-storage, airflow, google-cloud-composer

What is the proper way to access the root folder of the Composer's instance GCS bucket or any other airflow's folder (like /data) to save task's output file for a simple DAG:

```
import logging
from os import path
from datetime import datetime

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from airflow import models
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator


def write_to_file():
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(5, 5)),
                      columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
    logging.info("Saving results")

    file_path = path.join("output.csv")

    df.to_csv(path_or_buf=file_path, index=False)


with models.DAG(dag_id='write_to_file',
                schedule_interval='*/10 * * * *',
                default_args={'depends_on_past': False,
                              'start_date': datetime(2018, 9, 8)}) as dag:
    t_start = DummyOperator(task_id='start')

    t_write = PythonOperator(
        task_id='write',
        python_callable=write_to_file
    )

    t_end = DummyOperator(task_id='end')

    t_start >> t_write >> t_end
```

Is there some environment variable set or should I use GCS hook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got answer on the composer mailing list "if you save operator output data to `/home/airflow/gcs/data`, it will be auto synced to the `gs://{composer-bucket}/data`".

Comment: what do you mean "save operator output data"?

Comment: df.to_csv("/home/airflow/gcs/data/filename.csv") works??

Comment: Yes, it works! I meant that operator uses some hook (connection to db/file) and saves query results to GCS.

Comment: what will be the way to access other bucket data, whcich is not related to composer bucket ? see stackoverflow question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57586365/how-we-can-access-any-configuration-file-from-other-bucket-instead-of-composer

Comment: what will be the way to access other bucket data, whcich is not related to composer bucket ? see stackoverflow question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57586365/how-we-can-access-any-configuration-file-from-other-bucket-instead-of-composer