# How we can access any configuration file from other bucket (instead of composer bucket)

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am new in python and google composer.
I am trying to read configuration(.properties) file from google cloud storage from my python script. configuration files contain key & value pair.
I tried with configparser for reading the config file & normal with operator also
If same file we have in same composer environment then we can give the path 
like '/home/airflow/gcs/dags/config.properties'

But for other bucket what path I can give ??

I am trying to access path storage_client using below code

```
separator = "="
keys = {}

def iterate_bucket():
    bucket_name = 'other-bucket'
    storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(
    '/home/airflow/gcs/data/*************.json')
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blobs = bucket.list_blobs()
    return blobs

def read_Prop():
    blobs = iterate_bucket()

    for blob in blobs:
        if "config.properties" in blob.name:
            print("hello : ", blob.name)
            #file_name = "/home/airflow/gcs/" + blob.name
            file_name = blob.name

    with open(file_name, 'r') as f: 
       for line in f:
       if separator in line:

            name, value = line.split(separator, 1)
           keys[name.strip()] = value.strip()

print(keys.get('any_key'))
```

I used configparser also

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read(blob.name)
```

In both the condition for other google cloud storage(bucket) is not accesible from my python script.
I am getting no such file or directory error

What path we can give or any other way to access ??

Example 2 -

```
def readYML():
bucket_name = 'external-bucket'
storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(
    '/home/airflow/gcs/data/private-key.json')
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
file_name = ""
blobs = bucket.list_blobs()
print("blobs : ",blobs)
for blob in blobs:
    if "sample_config.yml" in blob.name:
        print("hello : ", blob.name)
        file_name = blob.name
        print("file_name : ",file_name)
with open(file_name, 'r') as ymlfile:
    CFG = yaml.load(ymlfile)
    print("inside readYML method : ", CFG['configs']['project_id'])
    return CFG
```

see the logs - Here in print statement file name is coming but when we are reading getting error for NO such file or directory error.

```
[2020-01-02 12:39:12,853] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 11782: 
Subtask Raw1 [2020-01-02 12:39:12,852] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - hello :  
sample_config.yml
[2020-01-02 12:39:12,853] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - file_name :  
sample_config.yml
[2020-01-02 12:39:12,853] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 11782: 
Subtask Raw1 [2020-01-02 12:39:12,853] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - 
file_name :  sample_config.yml
[2020-01-02 12:39:12,855] {models.py:1846} ERROR - [Errno 2] No such file or 
directory: 'sample_config.yml'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use the Google Cloud Console and look up the path for each object in your bucket. You will see how they are named. However, you cannot use the standard file I/O library to read objects. You need to use the same SDK as you are using to get the names to read the objects (except if the objects are public then you would use an HTTP request library).

Comment: Note You have some issue with your code. For example, referencing `blob.name` after the for loop (or is your indenting wrong in your code display?).

Comment: there is no indention error, in code display is wrong, anyway I changed it

Comment: At security point of you, I recommend you to not store and use a JSON key file. It's better to use the identity of Composer and to authorized this service account on your bucket (as Object Reader only, if no other action are required).

Comment: Hi @BhageshArora if you still experience this issue, can you add complete error trace to your post, to further investigate you issue? However, if the issue is resolved by now, can you post the answer and accept it, for the better visibility of the resolution?

Comment: Hi @PawelCzuczwara, Still I am facing same issue - I am able to access the object/file from bucket But not able to read the file. here I am trying to readh YML file so YMLfile is accessible but not able to read the Data, see above example 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't access any configuration file from composer bucket. we can only access the file using storage access API but directly we can't read any property file from any other bucket.